# I am creating an array and I want to specify it's length from a constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, error-handling

In my C# code, I have 2 classes, one is called "Names" and it is pretty simple as you can see, it has an indexer and an array, the other class is the "Program class" which has the Main method

```
    class Names
{
    private static int _length;
    private static string[] namesArray = new string[_length];

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get => namesArray[i];
        set => namesArray[i] = value;
    }

    public Names(int length)
    {
        _length = length;
    }
}

    class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Names names = new Names(10);
        names[0] = "Jerry";
        Console.WriteLine(names[0]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

when I run the code.. it gives me an "IndexOutOfRangeException" as the names array is empty..
I tried to hardcode the array length to 10 instead of passing "_length" to the array.. and it worked well..
I also tried to make the _length variable non-static but it gave me an error and it has to be static...
I tried to debug it and know where is the error.. and I discovered that the "_length" variable is 10 as I assign it from the constructor.. but when I pass the variable to the array the array is still empty.
I only need to specify the array length from a constructor.

Comment: This is very clearly nothing to do with Unity since it's a console application. Further more, the `[visual-studio]` tag is incorrect because this question isn't about the Visual Studio _application_, and the tag info states that you shouldn't use it for code that was merely authored using Visual Studio. Please take care to only add appropriate tags. At best it irritates those who follow the tags that are inappropriately used, at worst it makes your question confusing because you're giving us incorrect information about your project.

Comment: explore the meaning and the implications of the 'static' modifier. Long story short, this means static in memory info, this is, that the info will stay there and wont vanish. However this concept has a bit of insight and the inicialization might be tricky, as it is not the same as the regular non static elementes. You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) out for a start. Note that static variable that must be initialized at run time, not as your array initialization :)

Comment: hope this help to share code and try it https://rextester.com/live/NRKW7686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove initialization of array because its **_length** variable not set yet

Also Remove **Static** Keyword because its not use here

```
private string[] namesArray;
private int _length;
```

Initialization from Constructor

```
public Names(int length)
{
    _length = length;
    namesArray = new string[_length];
}
```